# Owin Self-Hosted WebApi MaxBufferSize

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin

When I host WebApi with IIS or WebApi Selfhost, I can set values for MaxBufferSize and MaxReceivedMessageSize.

But what about Owin Self-Host? Is there any way to define those parameters? Didn't found anything. Is there no need todo that? If there is no need, can you explain why?

Answer (score 0):

As you may know, Microsoft has shifted towards middleware. This [article](http://forums.asp.net/t/1966232.aspx?Web%20API%20OWIN%20Host%20Limit%20Request%20Size) has a ready to use example to enforce the maximum message size. Basically you need to create a class that inherits OwinMiddleware and then you can inspect your message size on the IOwinRequest interface in the current context.

It's weird that two lines of code need to be replaced by a lot of complicated code for such a 'simple' task, but that's the way it is.

Comment: This seems to do something only if you want to lower the limit; at least it seems to me that the middleware is only ever invoked for requests smaller than the default limit.

Comment: This turned out to have nothing to do with the middleware but instead somehow with authentication: My OwinHttpListener was set up to use IntegratedWindowsAuthentication as its AuthenticationSchemeSelectorDelegate. If I remove that entirely, the middleware is invoked in either case. Not sure what causes this, or how to work around it, though.

Comment: For reference, I've added this [as another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59707967/5085211).