# Sending large POST requests with integrated Windows authentication in OWIN self-host

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin, windows-authentication, ntlm

I'm trying to set up an endpoint for authenticated HTTP POST requests that will handle requests whose bodies sit at around 15 kB.

I followed the [description on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/enabling-windows-authentication-in-katana#windows-authentication-in-httplistener) and defined

```
var httpListener = (OwinHttpListener) appBuilder.Properties[typeof(OwinHttpListener).FullName];
httpListener.Listener.AuthenticationSchemeSelectorDelegate = request =>
    request.HttpMethod == "POST"
        ? AuthenticationSchemes.IntegratedWindowsAuthentication
        : AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous;
```

in my `Startup.Configuration`. This works like a charm for smaller requests, but I end up with HTTP 400 Bad Requests the moment I try to send through a request with a body size of about 15 kB. To test this, I'm using

```
curl -v --ntlm --negotiate -u {username}:{password} -d @myfile.txt http://localhost:8080/my-endpoint
```

where `myfile.txt` is about 15 kB. At first, I assumed this was an issue about Content-Length being limited and implemented the [middleware suggested in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37870422/5085211) to change the limit; this was a red herring, though, as the middleware ends up being invoked only for smaller requests. Indeed, if I get rid of the authentication entirely, everything works as expected.

Moreover, if I use `AuthenticationSchemes.Ntlm` instead of `AuthenticationSchemes.IntegratedWindowsAuthentication`, then the curl request does goes through without any issues, so I have a functioning workaround, but I am still curious what is causing the issue in the first place, and if there is a workaround that doesn't rely on falling back to NTLM.

Comment: Curious if you see the exception / error details - returned by OWIN process along with 400

Comment: No CLR exceptions are caught (by VS), and the HTTP 400 response is empty.

Comment: Are you running this behind an IIS instance or is it self-hosted?

Comment: In the case of no caught exceptions, check the windows event logs for more details.

Comment: @Brannon: Self-hosted (cf. question title).

Comment: @Matt: Where in the logs would you expect this to show up? The Windows logs show nothing